# ANDR-PERF tryGetService failed; SELinux

Tags: android, kotlin, logcat, selinux

everytime I start my app on a device I see this error in my logs.

E/ANDR-PERF: IPerf::tryGetService failed!
E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.perf::IPerf pid=3328 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c123,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:hal_perf_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0

I'm a bit confused what this means. 
Maybe one of my libraries is causing this?

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

//General Stuff
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$compile_version"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$compile_version"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$compile_version"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$compile_version"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$compile_version"
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$compile_version"

//Test
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//Testfairy
implementation 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.9.4'

//REST - MVVM
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

//Location
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

//Async Tasks
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.0"

//Barcode Detector
//OCR Scanner
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'

//Biometric Authentication
implementation 'com.kevalpatel2106:fingerprint-dialog-compat:1.0'

//Glide Image manager
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

//Image Viewer
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'

//EditText Label Design
implementation 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'

//Segmented Control
implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'

//Progress Bar
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'

//BlurView
implementation 'com.wonderkiln:blurkit:1.0.0'

//Tags
implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'

//Seek Bar
implementation 'com.ramotion.fluidslider:fluid-slider:0.3.0'

//Rating View
implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'

//Country Code Picker
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: What is your device's SELinux status? (It's in the About Phone screen of system settings)

Comment: Sorry i don't know what you are mean? I don't see anything about selinux in the about phone screen of the system settings

But its a oneplus 5t with android version 9

Answer (score 0):

This log file means one of your libraries had an access (It might be interface=vendor.qti.hardware.perf::IPerf) violation. You have to restart your app and find the problematic app. Also you can find with help of

```
adb shell ps -eZ | grep  3328
```

command the problematic service from command line as your app running at the same time. After you find the victim(app) you have to add /external/sepolicy/service_contexts file a SELinux rule for handling the access violation.

Comment: thank you for your answer! it tried a long time to figure out what you mean. can you tell me how to add such a rule?

Comment: You should investigate some useful tools like SETools and policycoreutils-python(audit2allow). First you tee your avc denial log into a log file. Then use audit2allow to get solution about your denials. After that you have  a lot of choices to add correct solution. You can apply your files correct domain or you can bypass with semanage booleans or if not you can add new lines to your selinux rules file, compile it. Solution exactly depends on the problem and your system configuration.

Comment: One last question. Is this a bug of my app or something other? because on other devices i don't have this errors

Comment: From your notes, I think it is most probably another app or library which is trying to reach HAL layer perf_hwservice. You should get info about problematic app from command which I mentioned inside the answer. If ps -eZ doesn't return anything, it has already dead.

Comment: The result of the command says that my app causes that errors.

Comment: Then, you should reconsider about writing an allow rule from source to target perf_hwservice.Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be an issue in Blurkit library.